# MATLAB fourier image filtering

Tags: image, matlab, filtering

I am currently learning how to filter images using Fourier transform in Matlab. I managed to apply a low pass filter on an image, the problem is, I cannot do the same with high pass filter. Here are codes and images that I got. Could you help me?

```
clc

clear

A=imread('3.tif'); % image size is 200 x 200

B=fftshift(fft2(A));

mask=zeros(200);

mask(80:120,80:120)=1;

C=mask.*B;

D=ifft2(C);

D=uint8(D);

imshow(D);
```

Here the results:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2UaI.png

The problem occures when I try to apply an inverse mask, like so:

```
clc

clear

A=imread('3.tif'); % image size is 200 x 200

B=fftshift(fft2(A));

mask=zeros(200);

mask=mask+255;

mask(80:120,80:120)=0;

C=mask.*B;

D=ifft2(C);

D=uint8(D);

imshow(D);
```

Results:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzYNG.png

What is wrong?

Comment: Your D matrix is actually going to be 16 bits in the above code, so when you convert it into a uint8, you are not getting meaningful information back.  This is why the first answer below works, and why your first code works.

Comment: See this answer for an example of FFT filtering: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22637290/2777181, replace this line `MaskedFFT=fftshift(fft2(f));.*Mask;` by `MaskedFFT=fftshift(fft2(f));.*(1-Mask);` to turn into high pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this on the second code:

```
mask=zeros(200);
mask=mask+255;
```

... to this

```
mask=ones(200);
```

You also forgot to call `ifftshift` on both codes:

```
D=ifft2(ifftshift(C));
```

Here is what I got:

- **Lowpass:**

[image]

- **Highpass:**

[image]